# unexpected SIGTTIN after `bash -ic "/bin/echo hello"` when bash scripting

Tags: bash, shell

This is the binary `the_binary`:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
int main(void){   
    char rbuf[10];   
    int ret;
    if((ret = read(0, rbuf, 10)) < 0){   
    }   
    printf("read content:%s\n",rbuf);   
    return 0;   
 }
```

This is the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash -ic "/bin/echo $$"
./the_binary
```

Try it, you will observe that

```
➜ test ./the_script.sh # clarify: test is the part of prompt, but not the commmand, please ignore it
hello
[1]  + 25407 suspended (tty input)  ./bash.sh
```

As far as I know, `bash -ic "/bin/echo hello"` did some thing to make the binary send a `SIGTTIN` signal to the process executing the script.

But what happened? What is the semantics of `bash -ic`?

Other problem scripts are:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash -ic "/bin/echo hello"
bash -ic "/bin/echo hello"
```

and,

```
#!/bin/bash
bash -ic "/bin/echo hello"
python -ic "print 'hello'"
```

**EDITED**: rename the binary to clarify the problem

Comment: What is `test` here? It's not the standard command.

Comment: `bash -i` makes the shell interactive even if standard input is not a terminal; is `test` executing its argument?

Comment: I don't follow your examples. It looks like you're running the bash builtin `test` with a file as an argument, but that's not going to run the script. It's just going to return 0.

Comment: `SIGTTIN` happens when a program that's running in the background tries to read from the terminal. There doesn't seem to be anything in your question that runs the script in the background, but maybe it has something to do with your version of `test`. You really should avoid giving your own programs the same name as standard Unix commands like `read` and `test`.

Comment: sorry I'm using zsh here, `test` is just the directory name. I have removed it.

Comment: @Barmar `SIGTTIN` also happens when some process sends it to the process :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's bash that tries to do something clever (again! I still remember shellshock. And [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/39020633/answer/79279418#comment-111083118) (in Chinese) is another one).

`strace -f` the script, and you'll notice that `SIGTTIN` is sent by bash, not kernel. Search the source code and you'll see this in jobs.c:

```
  if (shell_pgrp == 0)
{
  shell_pgrp = getpid ();
  setpgid (0, shell_pgrp);
  tcsetpgrp (shell_tty, shell_pgrp);
}

  while ((terminal_pgrp = tcgetpgrp (shell_tty)) != -1)
{
  if (shell_pgrp != terminal_pgrp)
    {
      SigHandler *ottin;

      ottin = set_signal_handler(SIGTTIN, SIG_DFL);
      kill (0, SIGTTIN);
      set_signal_handler (SIGTTIN, ottin);
      continue;
    }
  break;
}
```

Why the second (and the third, if you put one there) bash sends `SIGTTIN` but not the first?

Because the first time, `shell_pgrp == terminal_pgrp` (the process executing the script). Then the interactive bash sets itself as the group process and the foreground process group. Then it exits.

The second (and the third if you have) bash sees the process group is the process executing the script (this is a new group), but the terminal's foreground process group is still the exited first bash (the executor doesn't do any job control since it's executing a script uninteractively). So `shell_pgrp != terminal_pgrp` and the `kill` part above executes.

`man 4 tty_ioctl` and `tcsetpgrp` if you need some docs.

zsh doesn't kill like this.

---

For this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash -ic "which mvn"
python -ic "print('hello')"
```

You don't receive a `SIGTTIN`. You receive a `SIGTTOU` instead, because Python tries to output something while it's not the foreground process group (the first, exited bash is). (And if you do receive a `SIGTTIN`, that because `python -i` by definition, reads from the terminal. `SIGTTOU` may not be sent from the kernel depending on your terminal settings.)